# Tomcat / jBOSS sessions - where are they usually stored?

Tags: java, tomcat, application-server

Preface: I'm not a java developer.

I have a question about Tomcat / jBOSS and other java application servers.  Where are sessions (session data) stored?  In PHP, sessions are usually stored in the database which means you can easily share session data in a load balanced environment.  In Tomcat and other application servers, session seem to be stored in memory by default which would not apply in a load balanced env.  While it is true that PHP stores sessions in files by default, it takes a few lines to hook it up to a DB.  Is the same true of applications servers?

Basically, what's the pros for storying sessions in memory?  Is this still standard practice for application servers?  Thanks all!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I have a question about Tomcat / jBOSS and other java application servers. Where are sessions (session data) stored?

By default, I'd say in memory. Details are actually... implementation details which are application server specific.

> In PHP, sessions are usually stored in the database which means you can easily share session data in a load balanced environment. In Tomcat and other application servers, session seem to be stored in memory by default which would not apply in a load balanced env.

Well, not exactly. What this means is that a client request has to be sent to the same node in a clustered environment (this is referred to as "session stickiness") and this is not an issue from a load balancing point of view. But this is an issue from a failover point of view: in case of failure of a node in a cluster, session state managed by the node can be lost. To solve this, almost all application server providers implement session failover (using various mechanism such as in-memory replication, JDBC-based persistence, etc). But, again, implementation details are application server specific. See for example how [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html) or [WebLogic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/cluster/failover.html#wp1022034) deal with that. The [Under the Hood of J2EE Clustering](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=J2EEClustering) article on The Server Side is a very interesting reading too.

> While it is true that PHP stores sessions in files by default, it takes a few lines to hook it up to a DB. Is the same true of applications servers?

As I said, not all application servers will offer JDBC-based persistence. Having that said, and to answer your question, configuration is in general simple when they do. But using a database is really not the preferred solution (actually, I avoid it at all price).

> Basically, what's the pros for storying sessions in memory? Is this still standard practice for application servers?

Simply: performance! Serializing data, calling a database, writing to disk, all this has a cost. In-memory replication obviously allows to avoid some overhead. But it has some limitation too. For example, it doesn't allow [WAN HTTP Session State Replication](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/cluster/failover.html#wp1040361) with WebLogic. But well, only few people need this :)

Comment: @frio80 You're welcome! BTW, the common way of recognizing a good answer is upvoting it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

With the provided Session Manager, the session is always in memory but it has a manager to persist the session to JDBC store,

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/manager.html

Unlike in PHP, the session is still accessed from memory and it's only persisted to DB when the memory limit is reached or at server shutdown. So your load-balancer must have sticky routing for this to work.

The benefit of in-memory session is performance because db access doesn't occur for every transaction.

You can write your own session manager to simulate the PHP behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaEE spec does not dictate this, it is up to the individual implementations to decide. For example, the usual way to handle load balancing in Tomcat is to use [replicated sessions](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/cluster-howto.html), where the session data is multicast between the nodes. Storing session data in the database is a huge performance killer, and while Tomcat may support it, I really wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks.  I see that there are three methods for replicated sessions (file, JDBC, and in-memory).  So file / in-memory are most common?  I think my issue is I dont really understand what an "application server" entails.  I need to do more reading.

Comment: I'd love to read some data behind the "Storing session data in the database is a huge performance killer" statement, have any references? (Not disparaging, interested.) I'd expect it would be massively dependent on the infrastructures involved.

Comment: @TJ: applications often store considerably amounts of highly structured, highly volatile data in their sessions, which can be prohibitively expensive to persist in a database in a scalable way. If you move your application from in-memory to in-database session persistence, in can often kill the performance. Network-replicated in-memory sessions get around that problem to a large degree, in that while there is a performance hit for doing the replication, it's generally much less pronounced than with database persistence.