# tomcat/jboss session store

Tags: session, tomcat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tomcat / jBOSS sessions - where are they usually stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922048/tomcat-jboss-sessions-where-are-they-usually-stored)

Where does tomcat or jboss for that matter store the session data?
And if it stores those in-memory then how does it do the session management in clustered environment? I mean how the fail over is taken care of without loosing the sessioncontext. Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Hemant

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1922048/1140748

Answer (score 0):

By default Tomcat stores session data in memory.

When using clustering there are two approaches: DeltaManager and BackupManager.

With the DeltaManager changes to the session on one node are replicated to every other node in the cluster. If one node dies, the full session is available at whichever node the client fails over to.

With the BackupManager things are a little more complicated. For each session, one node is the primary node (that the client accesses), one node is the backup (where a full copy of the sessions is maintained) and all the other nodes are proxy sessions (they only know where the primary and backup sessions are - they contain no data). When a node dies, clients pick another node at random. If they pick the backup node, that node becomes the primary, a new backup is selected and all the proxies are updated. If they pick a proxy node, that node becomes the primary, copies the data from the backup and all the proxies are updated. For this to work, sticky sessions must be used.

I often find it helps when thinking about the BackupManager to consider four nodes (A, B, C & D) in a cluster that is supporting 60 user sessions. Since sessions are distributed in a round-robin way to nodes, you should end in the following state:

Node A will have 15 primary sessions, 5 sessions backed up for node B, 5 backups for node C and 5 backups for node D. It will also have 30 proxy sessions for the remaining sessions that detail which nodes are their primary and backup.

Node B will have 15 primary sessions, 5 sessions backed up for node A, 5 backups for node C and 5 backups for node D. It will also have 30 proxy sessions for the remaining sessions that detail which nodes are their primary and backup.

Node C will have 15 primary sessions, 5 sessions backed up for node A, 5 backups for node B and 5 backups for node D. It will also have 30 proxy sessions for the remaining sessions that detail which nodes are their primary and backup.

Node D will have 15 primary sessions, 5 sessions backed up for node A, 5 backups for node B and 5 backups for node C. It will also have 30 proxy sessions for the remaining sessions that detail which nodes are their primary and backup.

There are also lots of configuration options to control how and when the data is replicated between the nodes. See the Tomcat docs for details.

Comment: By default which one tomcat uses? delta or backup?

Comment: By default, neither since clustering isn't enabled by default. If you enable clustering, the DeltaManager is used by default.